# JavaScript setTimeout not working with prompt box

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```
var t = setTimeout("increment();", 1000 * 3);

var st;

function increment() {
    st = 1;
}

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    cnt = i;
    var no1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
    var no2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);

    if ((i % 4) == 0) {
        crct_ans[i] = no1 + no2;
        quest[i] = no1 + " + " + no2;
    }
    else if ((i % 4) == 1) {
        crct_ans[i] = no1 - no2;
        quest[i] = no1 + " - " + no2;
    }
    else if ((i % 4) == 2) {
        crct_ans[i] = no1 * no2;
        quest[i] = no1 + " x " + no2;
    }
    else if ((i % 4) == 3) {
        crct_ans[i] = no1 / no2;
        quest[i] = no1 + " / " + no2;
    }

    ans[i] = prompt(quest[i], "");

    if (st == 1) break;
}​
```

I want to stop the for loop if 3 seconds pass. But this is not working. For loop runs after the 3 seconds also. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it suits your requirements, you can simply check how much time pass.

Example:

```
var start = new Date();

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    var end = new Date();
    var elapsed = end.getTime() - start.getTime();

    if (elapsed >= 3000)
        break;
}​
```

Comment: This is working. Thanks. If you can please explain me why my code isn't working.

Comment: @JKAUSHALYA. I think it's because the `prompt` locks the working thread, so the time freezes until it is closed. while the real time doesn't freeze since the creation of the world...

Answer (score 3):

Remove `()` and quotes like this:

```
var t = setTimeout(increment, 3000);
```

- Removing `()` disables running of that function straright away/immediately whereas `setTimeout` expects callabck.
- Removing quotes makes sure that `eval` isn't used behind the scenes.

---

BTW, it is good practice to declare all variables with single `var` keyword like this:

```
var t = setTimeout(increment, 3000), st;
```

Comment: For loop runs until ends. After 3 secs also.

Comment: Who said one line of var is best practice? I disagree, and dislike that one line option...

Comment: @gdoron: Who said ***one line of var*** ? :) I said one `var` keyword though you can span variables on next line too. BTW, you should read about javascript variable hoisting :)

Comment: @Sarfraz. O.k. but the question remains... who said it's best practice?

Comment: @gdoron: Check out JavaScript Variable Hoisting: http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting. Now it is upto you if you agree or not. I am not here to persuade you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try formatting like so:

```
var t = setTimeout(function(){increment();}, 3000);
```

Comment: Based on that, you probably have an error later in your script. Check your Javascript error console (CTRL SHIFT J for Chrome and Firefox, F12 for IE)

Comment: @JKAUSHALYA. what about [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10233607/601179)?

Comment: @KyleMacey I am using firebug. There isn't any errors. Still running until for loop ends.